# Trouble copying, writing to file, writing to new string buffer and concatenating a string in C

Tags: c, regex, http, printf

Having trouble with operations to do with the above mentioned functions. I am however able to print the output using the `printf();` function.
In an example to demo, we'll use the problematic write function which does not write anything to the created file.

```
void *problematic_write (void *arg) {
  char *host_match =(char *)arg;
  FILE *tmp_host = fopen("../tmp.txt", "arw+");
  if (tmp_host == NULL) {
    printf("Something went wrong creating file!");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  printf("%s", host_match);
  fprintf(tmp_host, "%s", host_match);
}
```

Earlier...

```
start_index = match_2[0].rm_so;
host_len = (match_2[0].rm_eo) - start_index;
host_match = (char * )malloc(host_len);
sprintf(host_match, "%.*s", host_len - 6, &clientbuffer_main[start_index + 6]);
host_match[host_len - 6] = '\0';
pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, problematic_write, (void *)host_match);
pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
```

Basically i'm extracting the `Host:` part of a http request.

Output:

```
localhost:8080
```

but nothing written to the file!

This is just an example of one of the operations i'm having trouble with.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the correct file? Try using an absolute path instead of a relative one to rule out any working directory confusion.

Comment: You never call `fclose` or `fflush`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that file opening mode `"arw+"` is incorrect. Please refer to the docs for valid modes.

Comment: `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` You are basically telling the program: if one of the threads has a problem, then just kill _all_ threads. You may want to fix that.

Comment: @RuudHelderman good looking

Comment: `pthread_exit(NULL);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The [file open](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) mode "arw+" is not defined by the standard. Unless the implementation defines a behavior in this case, it is undefined behavior to use this mode.
2. Writing a file with `fwrite()` does not necessarily cause the given data to be written immediately to the file. Instead, a file stream is normally buffered such that the data is first written to a buffer in RAM. On certain events, the buffer contents is written to the actual file. This can be forced by calling [`fflush()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) or [`fclose()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fclose).
3. The function is declared to return a pointer of type `void *`. However, there is no return statement.

With the use of the file in the OP function `problematic_write()`, it is sufficient to open in mode "a". Furthermore, the function ends without returning or saving the handle to the opened file. Thus, the file must be closed before returning. Finally, the function must be declared as `void` (or return a value):

```
void problematic_write (void *arg) {
  char *host_match =(char *)arg;
  FILE *tmp_host = fopen("../tmp.txt", "a");   // Open file with a defined mode
  if (tmp_host == NULL) {
    printf("Something went wrong creating file!");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  printf("%s", host_match);
  fprintf(tmp_host, "%s", host_match);
  fclose(tmp_host);   // Close the file
}
```

Comment: I fully agree that the file should be closed by calling `fclose`. However, it doesn't fully describe the "not write anything to the created file" part. As part of normal program termination, the file will be closed.

Comment: @SupportUkraine (1) Yes, I would expect that, but I suppose it is not guaranteed. I am honestly not sure if that or the non-standard open mode or both explains the behaviour. From a Standard perspective, the file is not required to be written in either case.

Comment: I'm (99.99%) sure the standard requires that all open files are flushed and closed under **normal** program terminations. The problem comes in case of abnormal termination where you can't be sure about buffered streams being flushed. So in any case, it's much better to do the explicit `fclose` as you recommend.

Comment: closing the file did it

Comment: Following up on why the other `cpy` and `cat` operations didn't work would be interesting to know. thanks

Comment: @kagami I didn't go into that because (1) there is no `cpy` or `cat` or any other concatenation attempt in the code you shared, (2) that belongs in a __separate question__.

Comment: @SupportUkraine "As part of normal program termination, the file will be closed." OP never mentioned the program terminates. OP's code may well have been part of a primitive web server implementation; a typical example of a program that provides content long before it terminates (if ever).

Comment: It is. It terminates long after. But the file closing seems to be the issue, however it occurs.